# Local host for all devices with router

Tags: apache, networking, local, easyphp

i trying to do t his fix below link n i restart the system every time i made changes but it also doesn't help i still get eorro when try to connect with other local devices. 
[Viewing localhost website from mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device)

i believe is router cause the problem

here is what i have for my pc setting

Windows 8 pro
easy php 14.1
and d-link router firmware version 7.17

Answer (score 0):

It could be the router but first you have to edit "conf_files\httpd.conf", find the line `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` and put the proper IP address.

Then restart your server.

Comment: Yes i have already done that.... i already change to my server ip. but what should i do to make the router work for it? cos after i change other local devices still doesn't load it.. sigh..