# Preview localhost as mobile/pad from my computer?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, localhost

I am wondering if there's a way to preview my asp.net localhost-website as it would look on another device, such as a mobile phone or pad. I want to do this on my computer, like this https://themes.shopify.com/themes/brooklyn/styles/brooklyn/preview.

I read this thread [Viewing localhost website from mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device) but I want to do it directly on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend BrowserStack or GhostLab

https://www.browserstack.com/

https://responsivedesign.is/resources/testing/ghostlab

Both Easy to configure and setup.

Otherwise if you only want to display in different solutions for different devices there is

http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

Answer (score 0):

I've a guide for your question.

1. Connect your wifi in mobile.
2. Open browser.
3. Enter your localhost project system IP address with colan and add web project folder name. for example, you system IP is 192.168.1.100 and web project directory name is demo, then navigate **192.168.1.100:demo** on mobile browser address bar.

you can able to preview your web project in smartphone or tablet.

Another simple method is Try to download opera emulator and test your localhost projects.

Link: http://www.helphin.com/how-to-preview-mobile-site-for-your-localhost-web-projects

Here I posted step by step instruction clearly. I hope it'll work for you./