# connect to local host with my android phone but dont the full angular site

Tags: angularjs, android-activity, localhost, tomcat8

I am using tomcat server and angularJS to build a site that uses an API to bring data from the server by using an HTTP requests. when running on local machine tomcat is on ,i can see the full functionality of the site but when i'm connecting to my localhost from my phone (through WiFi) the site i see is not really functioning ,as if the HTTP requests can't be sent. is there a way to make the site work fully when viewed from my phone ?

**note**: my site basically uses the API to send a GET request and update a table on screen with the data, and POST/DELETE requests to update,delete,create data and of course dynamically update the table.
i'm working with Windows 7 if it matters.

another note: i used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316959/2361718) to be able to connect with my phone. maybe i should use another way ?

Thanks
Sivan

Answer (score 0):

why not use https://ngrok.com/ to tunnel your localhost to an private url.

(this is just for mobile testing right?)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i installed ngrok, tried it and its not really working. before i could see the site partially loading. now ,nothing is loading ,the tunnel is not working. i'm waiting for an answer from ngrok guys.