# Localhost from Mobile Device Issue - net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: css, dns, localhost, device

I am trying to view my website in my mobile device by using **localhost** but my devices' browser are blocking my website to retrieve CSS and JS files.

***Extra Information: On my desktop, I using a VirtualHost to run my website.***

I also create a mobile view from local follow by these tutorials.

- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
- [Viewing localhost website from mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device)

I also set some inbound rule into my Firewall to allow port 80, 443 and 3306.

[image]

But when I view my local website from my device. It shows these errors.

[image]

I try to search some solution from Google. And some of the posts mentioned that it is because my DNS cannot be resolved.

But I'm not sure what is actual problem. I need some advises to rectify this issue.

Thanks.