# Compiling an ASP.NET 5 Web Application and generating DLL files

Tags: asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET 5 Web Application. While using **Class Library Projects**, I got some errors. So, I added class files and wrote my business logic and data access logic. After **Publishing** using Visual Studio, the Output folder contains the actual source code and compiled DLLs are not present. How can I share the compiled files with my client for deployment and not the actual source code?

By selecting the **Produce outputs on build** in the **Build** option, a DLL is generated. How can I use this DLL with **DNX** command for hosting?

In one of the sites, it was mentioned that we can Pre-compile the Web Application. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Ensure the **Produce Outputs on build** is checked in the **Build** Option. (Only if this option is checked, the `DLL` files will be generated.)

Step 2: Build the Web Application in **Release** mode.

Step 3: The compiled `DLLs` will be present in: `..\artifacts\bin\WebAppName\Release\dnx451`.

Step 4: The generated `DLLs` can be checked using **ILSpy**.

Step 5: Select the Web Application and click **Publish**.

Step 6: Go to the published path: `..\approot\src\WebAppName` and delete all the `Class` files which were compiled into `DLLs` (after verifying Step 4). If `ViewModels` are used, those files should not be deleted as they will be used in `Views` (Refer Step 8).

Step 7: Copy the `DLLs` generated in Step 3 and paste in the published path: `..\approot\src\WebAppName`.

Step 8: Move all the `ViewModel` files into the `Views` folder.

Step 9: Open `Command Window` in the location: `..\approot\src\WebAppName`.

Step 10: Type `dnx --lib "..\approot\src\WebAppName" web` in the Command Window and click `Enter`. (Enter the path where the `Command Window` is opened.)

Step 11: Now, the `Kestrel Server` is Up and you can browse the Web Application by visiting `http://localhost:5000/`

**Note:** DNX is being [retired](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) in favor of the new [.NET Core Command LIne (CLI) Tools](https://github.com/dotnet/cli).

**Tip 1:** To view the application from a mobile device, please check: [Viewing localhost website from mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device).