# How to open localhost port on mobile device

Tags: web-deployment

I am running a Rails website on my Windows 8 computer's localhost. I want to try to run the website on my Android tablet. According to [this top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device?rq=1), to access the exact port from another device I must open the localhost port on my computer by adding an inbound rule to my firewall. I'm a beginner and I don't understand how to do this. Could somebody please go over this for me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to *run* the website on your tablet? The context suggest you only want to *view* or *open* it on your tablet.

Comment: Excuse my inexperience. Yes, I would like to view the website on my tablet.