# How to connect to other devices localhost through same router?

Tags: iis, networking, localhost, wifi, router

I tried to connect to an IIS from WiFi but I couldn't although I succeeded connecting to it while that device was connecting to the router via LAN.

How should I change the router settings to connect to other devices localhost when all the devices are connected to the router via WiFi?

Router model: TP-link TD-W8901N

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing localhost website from mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device)

Comment: @LexLi Nope! The problem is I can connect to the localhost of the other device, but ONLY when it's connected to the router via LAN cable. I don't know how to change the settings of the router in order to connect to the localhost via WiFi

Comment: See if you enabled any security feature https://www.howtogeek.com/179089/lock-down-your-wi-fi-network-with-your-routers-wireless-isolation-option/ In general this question is vendor specific, so not a programming question at all, and does not belong here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, without using the DNS server, you couldn't access the web sites by using localhost url.

The only way you could access the site is using the ip address and the right port number.

You could firstly run ipconfig in the cmd tool on the IIS server.

Then you will record the IP address and the site's port number.

At last, you could use the IP address and the site prot number to access the sites.

Thr url like this: `http://192.168.1.3:8098`

Comment: I know the ip address and the port number and my device is connected to the same network as the website host. Please see the comments of the post