# Running Hybris development env in Mobile for debugging

Tags: debugging, mobile, localhost, sap-commerce-cloud

just curious if there is a way to run the Hybris website(development mode,i.e., https://localhost:9002) in the Mobile to check the UI/UX features.

I have tried several ways but didn't get success.
It would be helpful if anyone knows, meanwhile I am continuing my research on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you mean with 'run in mobile' ? You can set your browser in mobile mode and than call https://localhost:9002 then the site will be displayed in mobile variant.

Comment: Aside from Mafick's suggestion, you can also use a third-party BrowserStack to test different kinds of browsers / devices. The mobile mode on a desktop browser will sometimes not show the correct behavior. So, something like BrowserStack will be better.

Comment: you can try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316692/viewing-localhost-website-from-mobile-device#17316959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways in which you can check the UI/UX features in different screen sizes (Desktop / mobile / tablet):

1. **Hybris SmartEdit preview feature** - This is the most widely used method.

[image]

2. **Access the site using your laptop's IP address** (provided your mobile and laptop are in the same network) e.g. this is how it looks like when I access the site using `https://192.168.0.23:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/?site=electronics&clear=true` in my mobile phone:

[image]

The command to find the IP address is `ipconfig` in **Windows** and `ifconfig` in **MacOS**. You can also find the IP address using the **Control Panel** in **Windows** and **System Preferences** in **MacOS**.

3. **Using the [browser's device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode)** e.g.
   [image]

**Firefox:**

[image]